# find and click button once enabled selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find and click button once enabled. The website is the world tariff organization data for import export fees. Here's the address:

http://tariffdata.wto.org/ReportersAndProducts.aspx

The "Next" Button on the upper right corner gets enabled once a "Reporter" and a "Product" element are both selected.

I am able to select all of the reporters and products using selenium and python like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/lopez/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://tariffdata.wto.org/ReportersAndProducts.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td.common_link:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1) > b:nth-child(1)').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td.common_link:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1) > b:nth-child(1)').click()
```

However I haven't been able to find and click the "Next" Button in order to get to the next page which is the report downloads page.

Here's the portion of the html code pertinent to the "Next" Button:

```
</div>

<div id="ctl00_ContentView_UpLinkButtonNext">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr style="height: 15px">
            <td style="height: 15px">
            </td>
        </tr>         
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right" class="common_link_bold">
                <div class = "button_text_icon right">
                    <a id="ctl00_ContentView_LinkButtonNext" disabled="disabled" class="disabled">Next</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I find and click the "Next" button once it becomes enabled?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for enabled Next button as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[not(@class='disabled') and .='Next']"))).click()
```

Comment: It still doesn't find and click the "next" button. Here's the error I get: TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: There was a typo. Try now

Comment: We just waiting for Next button which doesn't contain `class="disabled"`, so once this class name removed from Next button, we can click it. Pleas mark answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why this method `element_to_be_clickable` needs to be called, actually If we simply write `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[not(@class='disabled') and @id='ctl00_ContentView_LinkButtonNext1']")).click` it works fine(giving implicit wait). This is just waiting for this particular element to exist. Element to be clickable function goes out of scope in this place.

Comment: I guess Implicit wait might also be applied, but I never suggest this approach as Implicit wait is not so flexible and useful as Explicit wait

Comment: Okay, let's leave implicit wait now. But my point of argument is, you are just waiting for  this element `//a[not(@class='disabled') and @id='ctl00_ContentView_LinkButtonNext1']` to exist, so why element_to_be_clickable method is used? I tried with `visibilityofelement` element as well, it works too. So May I know the reason for using element_to_be_clickble?

Comment: Hi, this problem seems to be interesting one, the given waiting statement is waiting just element to exist, it's not waiting for element_to_be_clickable, so the question.

Comment: `element_to_be_clickable()` means that element is already present in DOM (`presence_of_element_located()` returns `True`) and visible (`visibility_of_element_located()` returns `True`). As we want to click something it's better to use `element_to_be_clickable()` as next time `presence_of_element_located()` or `visibility_of_element_located()` might not work properly to locate *clickable* element, so OP will be confused

Comment: yes, thank you! I am well aware of the fact that element's existence and element visibility is needed for element_to_be_clickable but I am saying, it's not checking whether element is clickable, it's only make sure element exist and element visible, it's not really checking whether element is clickable, for an example, execute this statement `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ctl00_ContentView_LinkButtonNext1"))).click();`, this throws the error of ElementClickInterceptedError, this says to me that it's not checking whether element is clickable.

Comment: I'm using Python and I cannot reproduce the issue with `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentView_LinkButtonNext'))).click()` - I get no errors

Comment: I am not getting errors either! I am saying element_to_be_clickable is not doing it's work is my point. And also there is something very interesting is happening in this place, If you directly click using the id of that next button, it's throwing 'ElementClickInterceptedError`, this error happens only when some other element is obscuring the element, and this error is being thrown when I click using id,(continued..)

Comment: when this error happens, you can't form any other locator to that element to perform the operation but your xpath is making find_element to wait until it is ready to trigger the action. Something very interesting behavior I am observing here. That's what triggers the curious in me as to what makes this happens1

Comment: Okay, fine, I don't want to trouble you much, I leave the conversation here, Let me do a bit of investigation in this place by myself. Thank you for the discussion!

Answer (score 2):

You can use explicit wait to wait for the button to be clickable

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentView_LinkButtonNext')))
element.click()
```

`element_to_be_clickable` will check if the button is enabled. From the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable)

> An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such
>   that you can click it.

Notice you need to add some imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

Comment: I don't get errors it just doesn't find and click the next button

Comment: This is because in this case `element_to_be_clickable()` doesn't work as @Guy expected. Note that `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentView_LinkButtonNext'))).is_enabled()` returns `True` even if none checkboxes selected...

Comment: @LuisLopez There are two `next` buttons, one if id `'ctl00_ContentView_LinkButtonNext` and one if id `'ctl00_ContentView_LinkButtonNext1` (the upper one). Maybe you need to click it.

Comment: the upper one just expands o compresses the reporters object